# Iterate through undefined length of sub arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

how to iterate through this variable where sub could have 10 more subs for ex.?

```swift
struct Struct {
    let title: String
    let sub: [Struct]?
}

let variable = Struct(
    title: "1",
    sub: [
        Struct(title: "1.1", sub: nil),
        Struct(title: "1.2", sub: [
            Struct(title: "1.2.1", sub: nil),
            Struct(title: "1.2.2", sub: [
                Struct(title: "1.2.2.1", sub: nil)
            ])
        ])
    ]
)
```

Comment: The key thing is that my `display` calls `children.map { $0.display }`. If every node prints and tells its children to print, you’ve printed them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s quite simple. Recurse. Let’s say we just want to print all titles. Imagine a method where a node prints its title and then calls *the same method* on each of its children. By definition if you call that method on the root node you have now printed all the titles. A minimal implementation (not worrying about visitation order or output format) would be:

```
func output() {
    print(title)
    self.sub?.forEach { $0.output() }
}
```